# Accessing Database in ViewModel vs Controller in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Let's say I have ViewModel

```
public class TestViewModel
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Link { get; set; }
}
```

Then in my controller

```
var model = new TestViewModel();
var obj = _uow.CallDB(); //call database
model.Description = obj.Description;
model.Link = obj.Link;

return View(model);
```

I find that I ended up using the same code over and over especially when `TestViewModel` is being used in a lot of pages. If I do something like

ViewModel

```
public class TestViewModel
{
    public class TestViewModel(bool init = false)
    {
        if (init)
        {
             var obj = _uow.CallDB(); //call database
             Description = obj.Description;
             Link = obj.Link;
        }
    }

    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Link { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
var model = new TestViewModel(true);
return View(model);
```

I know that putting database call in `ViewModel` violates the principle, but is there any more efficient way instead of having to write same shit over and over in the controller?

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: You can write code to create an implict conversion from your database entity to your ViewModel

Comment: Can you provide example?

Comment: Not only violates the principle, you are calling the db again in the POST method to overwrite the properties you have edited

Comment: To reduce the repetition, create a ViewModelService class to do your conversion. I place mine in the same layer (folder/ns) as the ViewModels. Optionally, use AutoMapper inside that service. But leave the code that calls the Db in the controller.

Comment: I like using a service to return db objects as well as update them. It keeps the various components nice and separate.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an [implicit conversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/implicit) from your database entity to your ViewModel. In this way you can simply assign the database model to your view model

```
void Main()
{
    DBModel t = new DBModel() { Description = "Google", Link = "http://www.google.com"};

    // Here the implicit conversion happens....
    // a DBModel is converted in a TestViewModel
    TestViewModel k = t;
    Console.WriteLine(k.Description);
    Console.WriteLine(k.Link);

    // This means that you could write this
    TestViewModel model = _uow.CallDB();
}

public class TestViewModel
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Link { get; set; }

    public static implicit operator TestViewModel(DBModel source)
    {
        if (source == null) return null;
        TestViewModel model = new TestViewModel()
        {
            Description = source.Description,
            Link = source.Link
        };
        return model;
    }
}

public class DBModel
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Link { get; set; }
}
```

Of course you can extend the implicit conversion for any future requirement.

Comment: @bommelding Not a great fan of it myself, but can you elaborate?

Comment: See my commnet under the question. But implicit/explicit operators require special circumstances, mostly applicable to immutable value types.